# Android emulator API level 25 Connect, no Internet

Tags: android-emulator

I tried all following tweaks, suggestions but couldn't able get Internet working on Android emulator. Using Android Studio: 3.1.4, emulator: Nexus 5X API 25

My computer has 2 network interfaces LAN, WiFi both are connected to Internet and working on computer.

1. I made my computer WiFi interface priority high from Network and
   Sharing -> Advanced.
2. I tried launching emulator with following

   emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_25_Play -dns-server 8.8.8.8

[Emulator WiFi configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/367Yu.png)

Comment: Internet worked without setting DNS and with only LAN connection on computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet worked without setting any DNS setting and only with LAN connection on computer. I just disabled proxy settings in emulator.